# The change of focal distance as a result of adding a substance

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses, camera

I have a given focal distance between lens and an image sensor (in air). Now I add a protective glass with a known refractive index and width between the lens and the sensor. How can I calculate the adjusted focal distance?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a bit of a subtlety here. Usually one would consider a medium with higher refractive index is *optical thick*, which means that a thickness of $d$ of such a medium corresponds to an equivalent thickness of $nd$ in air (vacuum), where $n$ is the refractive index. However, that works when considering the phase of the field.

In the scenario described here, the situation is different. For this situation one should rather use geometric optics. Then one finds that the medium with a higher refractive index of thickness $d$ represents a thickness of $d/n$ in air. So by inserting a flat piece of glass in the beam path, the focal point moves further away.

Comment: Doesn't this require a small angle approximation?